# Dates manipulation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a column with dates in my dataframe, that comes from csv file. I would like to add an extra column with number of the days between the dates in the column in my csv file and a date of 6/1/2021. Here is my code:

```
output['Actual Days Difference']= output['date'] - '6/1/2021'
```

ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (1320)

and this code doesn't work. I need to subtract 6/1/2021 from every date that in my dataframe's column "date"
Here is how my date column looks like in csv file:

```
date
7/15/2021
8/15/2021
```

Comment: You need to convert convert it to pd.to_datetime('6/1/2021')

Answer (score 1):

First cast your date to actual datetime and then get the difference of time

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.DataFrame({'date':['7/15/2021', '8/15/2021']})


dataf["Actual Days Difference"] = (pd.to_datetime(dataf['date']) - pd.to_datetime('6/1/2021')).dt.days

print(dataf)
# output

# date  Actual Days Difference
# 0 7/15/2021   44
# 1 8/15/2021   75
```